# Docker simultaneous build same machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, makefile, concurrency, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building a Docker image for node:10.20.1-buster-slim as base image and the Makefile runs fine, it creates the image and runs it.

However when using this Docker build in CI pipelines in Jenkins which is installed on a unique machine. Sometimes, the same image (node:10.20.1-buster-slim) is built from two processes simultaneously (e.g two Jenkins users run two Acceptance tests at the same time) so sometimes I end getting this kind of errors when trying to run the the container, after building the image:

```
failed to get digest sha256:3d3f18764dcb8026243f228a3eace39dabf06677e4468edaa47aa6e888122fd7: open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/3d3f18764dcb8026243f228a3eace39dabf06677e4468edaa47aa6e888122fd7: no such file or directory
```

Makefile targets:

```
define down
 docker-compose down
endef

define prune
 rm -rf build/dist/*.js.map build/dist/*.js build/dist/*.css
 docker container prune -f
 docker volume prune -f
 docker image prune -f
endef

build/dist/main.js: $(SRC)
    $(call down)
    $(call prune)
    chmod -R a+rw build
    docker build . --target=prod -t web_app_release
    docker run --mount type=bind,source="$(PWD)"/web_app/build,target=/opt/web_app/build --rm web_app_release npm run build-prod
    docker run --mount type=bind,source="$(PWD)"/web_app/build,target=/opt/web_app/build --rm web_app_release npm run build-css
```

Error (reproducible sometimes):

```
Compiling web_app ...
docker-compose down
Removing network webapp_default
Network webapp_default not found.
rm -rf build/dist/*.js.map build/dist/*.js build/dist/*.css
docker container prune -f
Total reclaimed space: 0B
docker volume prune -f
Total reclaimed space: 0B
docker image prune -f
Total reclaimed space: 0B
chmod -R a+rw build
docker build . --target=prod -t web_app_release
Sending build context to Docker daemon  122.5MB

Step 1/10 : FROM node:10.20.1-buster-slim AS base
 ---> cfd03db45bdc
Step 2/10 : ENV WORKPATH /opt/web_app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e1e61766fc45
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR $WORKPATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e776ef1390bd
Step 4/10 : RUN chown -R node $WORKPATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a5bb0d392a3
Step 5/10 : USER node
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bc682380a352
Step 6/10 : COPY --chown=node:node package* $WORKPATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 71b1848cad1e
Step 7/10 : RUN npm install --only=prod --no-progress
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de4ef62ab81e
Step 8/10 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 319f69778fb6
Step 9/10 : FROM base AS prod
 ---> 319f69778fb6
Step 10/10 : COPY --chown=node:node . $WORKPATH
 ---> 3d3f18764dcb
Successfully built 3d3f18764dcb
failed to get digest sha256:3d3f18764dcb8026243f228a3eace39dabf06677e4468edaa47aa6e888122fd7: open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/3d3f18764dcb8026243f228a3eace39dabf06677e4468edaa47aa6e888122fd7: no such file or directory
Makefile:91: recipe for target 'build/dist/main.js' failed
make[1]: *** [build/dist/main.js] Error 1
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'web_app' failed
make: *** [web_app] Error 2
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Build failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

How could I make it so that users could run tests concurrently without the build of the same image overlapping each other?

Could I use some tool included in docker or check manually with bash scripts or in the Makefile?

Comment: It seems likely to me in this sequence that one run's `docker image prune` is removing the image `docker build` is building basically exactly at the moment where the image has been built but before the builder gives it a tag.  That's surprising to me and I might consider filing a Docker bug, but if that's the case this sequence can't be run concurrently and you'll need some other sort of locking.

Comment: (Using a single image tag and a shared Compose setup means this setup can't run concurrently anyways.  Even absent this very specific problem you still have the risk that a second build creates a new `web_app_release` image before the first build can `docker run` the one it built, or that a build will `docker-compose down` the setup that integration testing is trying to use.)